# Paying VAT in foreign counties

Tags: european-union, selling, vat, world

I'm planning to sell (my own) software (yearly license actually) online, worldwide, from my Europe based company, **business to business only**. I'm really not into any financial topics but reading about it almost scared me away totally.

Did I get it right that for **each country** I make a sell in, I have to:

1. (before the sale) register a VAT number per country
2. create a receipt that conforms that country's laws (which can mean 200 types of different receipt templates)
3. pay the VAT for each country in different timeframes, e.g. I have to
   pay monthly in India, yearly in USA, etc?

+1: does the process differ within the European Union?

If the points I've written are just partly correct this seems to be a nightmare to manage. Is there any service which takes care of these for a certain fee?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a nightmare to manage on your own for a small company.  Fortunately, there are services that take of this for you and two examples are fastspring.com or paddle.com.

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't find them by Googling. Do you know if I need to use them within EU too, or it's somewhat simplified?

Comment: I've never used them.  I'm in the US so I don't need to deal with EU VAT.  I think their services are primarily for companies in the EU who have to deal with this.

Comment: It actually is trivial. See, the OP talks B2B, not "b2enduser". B2B you sell reverse charge without charging VAT. The rest is something handled easily.